# Problem with itemize and ifthenelse in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, itemize

I want to fill a cells of a table with only a `\item` command, and the `\begin{itemize}` should be automatically inserted. 
The following code works :

```
\newenvironment{matable}[0]{%
\begin{tabular}{l|p{5cm}}
theme & sujets \\ \hline\hline }
{\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\messujets}[1]{ & \begin{itemize} #1 \end{itemize}\\ \hline}

\begin{matable}
\messujets{\item subject 1 \item subject 2}
\end{matable}
```

With the command `\messujets` I start a new line in the table, and I fill the second cell with my `\item`. 
But if the argument of `\messujets` happens to be empty, LaTeX complains about a missing `\item`. 
To avoid this, I want to have an `\ifthenelse` test in the cell. My attempt is to replace:

```
\begin{itemize} #1 \end{itemize}
```

by

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\begin{itemize} #1 \end{itemize}}
```

So, it would be :

```
\newcommand{\messujets}[1]{ & \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\begin{itemize} #1 \end{itemize}}\\ \hline}
```

But this produces an error `use of \@item does not match its definition` which I do not understand...

Any idea?

Answer (score 11):

The reason for the problem is that the `\equal` argument is a so called moving argument. That means it will break if it contains in its argument commands that are fragile and not protected by `\protect`. And because of the optional argument `\item` is fragile.

In short using `\ifthenelse` here makes your life unnecessarily complicated as you would need to write something like

```
\messujets{\protect\item subject 1 \protect\item subject 2}
```

For that reason a better approach is to use a lowlevel solution where you test for the argument being empty in a way that nothing is getting expanded and breaks. There are a number of ways to do this, e.g.,

```
\ifx\foo#1\foo ...\else ... \fi
```

This will work as long as the argument `#1`doesn't start with `\foo` so by selecting some internal command for `\foo` you can make sure that this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{matable}
  {\tabular{l|p{5cm}} theme & sujets \\ \hline\hline }
  {\endtabular}
\newcommand\messujets[1]{ & \ifx\relax#1\relax\else\itemize#1\enditemize\fi\\ \hline}   
\begin{document}

\begin{matable}
  \messujets{\item subject 1 \item subject 2}
  \messujets{}
  \messujets{\item subject 3 \item subject 4}
\end{matable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Care to explain that? It also seems like a duplicate of Ian's.

Comment: see my answer. Herbert uses `\ifx` which works (as long as the arg doesn't start with `\relax`) while Ian uses `\if`which expands arguments and therefore is much more dangerous (and not quite correct as applied).

Comment: Thanks a lot  !
I often have problems when using ifthenelse, i think the reason is the same.

Comment: By the way : how should i do if i want a slightly more complicated test :
If #1 empty or #1 = somestring then nothing else itemize like before ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but I must be honest and admit that I don't really understand why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{matable}[0]{%
\begin{tabular}{l|p{5cm}}
theme & sujets \\ \hline\hline }
{\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\messujets}[1]{&\if\noexpand#1\relax\else \begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}\fi\\ \hline}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{matable}
\messujets{\item subject 1 \item subject 2}
\messujets{}
\messujets{\item subject 3 \item subject 4}
\end{matable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is quite risky: `\item \textbf{x}` would result in a disaster. Moreover the case in which `#1` is empty works because `\if` compares `\relax` to a special kind of `\relax` that's different from it: `\if\relax\else` is an incomplete conditional that TeX normalizes in a funny way.

Comment: Thanks egreg. The case where `#1` is empty was the part I didn't understand. Where can I read more about this special kind of `\relax`?

Comment: I think there's something about it in TeX by Topic. See also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_frm/thread/a01c3f260ca12a78/51011d76614e0dba)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `\item` you should consider a scheme like the second of the following, or use the multirow package. `\ifthenelse` will not work in this case. I had a look at the trace file and saw where the problem lies. The first of the following stands a better chance, but may still fail in some cases:

First case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\ifnotnull#1{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize{#1}$\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@iden\fi
}
\newenvironment{mytable}
  {\tabular{l|p{5cm}} theme & subjects \\ \hline\hline }
  {\endtabular}
\newcommand\subjects[1]{ & \ifnotnull{#1}{\itemize#1\enditemize}\\ \hline}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mytable}
  \subjects{\item subject 1 \item subject 2}
  \subjects{}
  \subjects{\item subject 3 \item subject 4}
\end{mytable}
\end{document}
```

Second case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxtools}[2011/12/10]
\newcount\colnum
\newcommand\generaterow[1]{%
  \colnum0
  \ltswhileexpr{\ifnum\colnum<#1\relax}{%
    &\global\advance\colnum by1 \the\colnum\relax
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
  \hline
  x\generaterow{3}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```